# Joining 3+ tables with join syntax in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I've been using joins for a long time, but it's always been the old syntax. Now I'm trying to figure out how to do basic inner joins with the JOIN syntax, and having trouble figuring it out.

Let's say I have 3 tables.

Employees:

```
EmployeeID      EmployeeName        DepartmentID
1               John Smith          2
2               Jane Doe            3
3               Mark Brown          1
```

Departments:

```
DepartmentID        DepartmentName      AreaID
1                   Sales               2
2                   Marketing           1
3                   Opeations           3
```

Areas:

```
AreaID      AreaName
1           Marketing
2           Sales
3           Opeartions
```

I need to get a list of all employee names with their departments and areas.

With the old syntax, I'd run the following query:

```
select e.EmployeeName, d.DepartmentName, a.AreaName
from employees e, departments d, areas a
where e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
and d.AreaID = a.AreaID
```

With the new syntax it seems that I can only join employees with departments, but not departments with areas in the same query. Or should I perhaps use a subselect?

Comment: select ... from t1 join t2 on t1.c = t2.c join t3 on t2.c = t3.c

Comment: The main difference is in the "order of things" - with the old, Oracle proprietary syntax, you enumerate all the tables you join in one shot, and then you put all the join conditions in the `where` clause. With the SQL Standard syntax, you name the first two tables to be joined and then immediately you add the join condition (`on ...`). Then you say `join third_table` and the join condition, showing how the third table is joined to the already existing join of the first two tables. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
select e.EmployeeName, d.DepartmentName, a.AreaName
from employees e  join departments d on e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
                  join areas a on d.AreaID = a.AreaID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I find [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) explanation of joins to be pretty useful.
Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName, d.DepartmentName, a.AreaName
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN departments d on e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN areas a on d.AreaID = a.AreaID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try left joining the `Employees`, `Departments`, and `Areas` tables, in that order.  We are meticulous here at Stack Overflow, and so we chose `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` because it handles the possibility that an employee may not have been assigned to a department, in which case the query would display `NA` as the value.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName,
       COALESCE(d.DepartmentName, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(a.AreaName, 'NA')
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN
Departments d
    ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
LEFT JOIN Areas a
    ON d.AreaID = a.AreaID
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've written is an alternative code for *Inner Join*.
You can use the code below.
So what I've done is Joined the Employee table to the Department table using the DepartmentID and Joined the Employee table to the Areas table using the AreaID.

```
Select e.EmployeeName
, d.DepartmentName
, a.AreaName
from employees e
INNER JOIN departments d
, areas a
ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN areas a
ON d.AreaID = a.AreaID
```